# How to understand the code of "q = i - 4; " in this answer?

Tags: c++, algorithm

> **Problem Description**
>
> A number sequence is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(n) = (A * f(n - 1) + B * f(n - 2)) mod 7.
> ```
>
> Given A, B, and n, you are to calculate the value of f(n).
>
> **Input**
>
> The input consists of multiple test cases. Each test case contains 3 integers A, B and n on a single line (1 <= A, B <= 1000, 1 <= n <= 100,000,000). Three zeros signal the end of input and this test case is not to be processed.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, print the value of f(n) on a single line.

**Sample Input**

```
1 1 3
1 2 10
0 0 0
```

**Sample Output**

```
2
5
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f[54] = {0, 1, 1};
int main()
{
    int A, B, n, q = 1;
    while (cin >> A >> B >> n && A && B && n)
    {
        for (int i = 3; i < 54; ++i)
        {
            f[i] = (A * f[i - 1] + B * f[i - 2]) % 7;
            if (i > 4)
            {   
                if (f[i - 1] == f[3] && f[i] == f[4]) //here too
                {
                    q = i - 4; //I can't catch the point
                }
            }
        }
        cout << f[n % q] << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: why dont you ask the person who wrote the code?

Comment: `cin >> A >> B >> n && A && B && n` is cute. If you wrote that then you're an expert and you would not be asking this question. Is this really your code?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ..btw I am not trying to be snarky with that comment, but code without comments and single letter variable names isnt very reader-friendly and the one who wrote it is really the one who should be able to explain it best

Comment: If it helps, I've been doing C++ for more than 20 years and I don't understand what q is either, this is awful code and whoever wrote it needs to go back to school.

Comment: @tobi303: I believe I've seen this code before on a certain online judge site.

Comment: It's not my homework .  I found this question on oj , and i didn't know how to solve it because of the problem of  length ((1 <= A, B <= 1000, 1 <= n <= 100,000,000)) ,then I found this answer on a blog , but the writer don't explain the code, he said:"you could think ablout why “

Comment: @Salmon Give us some context! This is hard enough to explain without having to try to work out what it's supposed to do as well. Give us the link to the blog post or whatever "oj" is.

Comment: the blog :http://www.cnblogs.com/hfc-xx/p/4655568.html   and the online judge site :http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/showproblem.php?pid=1005

Comment: From looking at the code one can only surmise that `f(n)` is periodic, that its period is `q`, and that the maximum period is 53-4=49 (which is 7*7). The `if` condition before `q = i - 4` detects periodicity. It should be consistent with the problem description, but I don't have time to write a complete answer right now.

Answer (score 11):

Given that `f(n)` is fully determined by `f(n - 1)` and `f(n - 2)` and any `f(x)` is an integer from 0 to 6, there are only 7*7=49 combinations of `f(n - 1)` and `f(n - 2)`. That means `f(x)` is periodic with a maximum period of 49. Once we know the period, calculating `f(n)` is as easy as `f(n % period)` given that we've calculated `f(0)..f(48)`. The exact period depends on `A` and `B` and needs to be calculated. In order to calculate the period, we simply need to find a repetition of two consecutive values of `f`. That is, if `f(x) == f(y) && f(x + 1) == f(y + 1)`, then `|y - x|` is either a period of `f` or an integer multiple of it. Note that `f(n) == f(n % (k*period))` works just as well as `f(n) == f(n % period)`. So, in the code in question `q` is either a period of `f` or an integer multiple of it.

Now, why does the code pre-calculate `f(0)..f(53)` rather than `f(0)..f(48)`? I think that's an overkill, as two extra elements beyond the maximum period would be sufficient.

Another troubling thing about the code in question is the fact that `f[0]` is a fake value, which may well be returned if `n` is a multiple of `q`. That's potentially a bug. To prevent it from happening, I would shift the indexing of `f` by one, making `f(0) == 1 && f(1) == 1` rather than `f(1) == 1 && f(2) == 1`.

Comment: I think that the potential bug would be problematic only if one would have to print the value for multiple `n` without doing the whole algorithm again.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this kind of problem should be an problem from OnlineJudge (OJ). Maybe you are new for ACM?

Blew is my answer:

All that why the solution could work is because `mod 7`, which means the answer could only be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. So, this problem looped only from 3 to 54 because that is enough. How to say, because f[n] is determined only with the two values before it f[n-1] and f[n-2], f[n-1] have 7 choice (0-6) so does f[n-2].

So loops with more 49 is enough, when some f[n-1] and f[n-2] equals to f[4] and f[3], the following values will be circulation.

Take your second example as a look.

```
f[1] = 1
f[2] = 1
A = 1
B = 2
n = 10 // or set n larger.
```

we will get

```
f[3] = 3
f[4] = 5
f[5] = 4
f[6] = 0
f[7] = 1
f[8] = 1
f[9] = 3
f[10] = 5
f[11] = 4
```

as `f[9] == f[3]` and `f[10] == f[4]`, then it will circulation after then with numbers, `4, 0, 1, 1, 3, 5`,

So `q = i - 4` removed the first four numbers, and as it the `n%q` is the is the position of the nth number in the circulation sequence.

I wonder if I have state the answer clearly, hope this helps you.

Comment: Do you mean because of the `mod 7`, only 7 different values can occur in the sequence, consequently there can be at most `7*7=49` different consecutive pairs in the sequence which is an upper bound for the length of the period?

Comment: Yes, as f[n] is only related to f[n-1] and f[n-2], each can be only 0-6, 7*7 = 49. so In length of 49 number must have a number k that f[k] == f[3] and f[k+1] = f[4].

Comment: Very insightful.

Comment: Perhaps the implementation would be more insughtful if it would determine the period length by checking for two consecutive `1` values, which are the initial values, instead of the ones with index `3` and `4`.

Comment: Sorry, No. It will get wrong answer if you use index 1 and 2, that is `f[1]=1, f[2]=1`. For example, `A=2` and `B=7`, then `f[1]=1,f[2]=1,f[3]=2,f[4]=4,f[5]=1,f[6]=2,f[7]=4`. You see never get continuous 1 and 1 (the first two index value). ACM (The ACM-ICPC International Collegiate Programming Contest) competition always set tricks like this to let the competition people get wrong.

Comment: Well ok - but why does it work with different indices then? The implementation explicitly uses `3` and `4` for checking, why does this work? Due to the so-called pigeon hole principle, there must be at least one pair of values repeating, but why will this be found at positions `3` and `4`?

Comment: I think this need mathematics prove that I currently not get. I will give a brief prove later if I could work it out. Good question!

Comment: Something fishy is going on here. Suppose that your argument ("although there is periodicity, the pair `1` and `1` does not necessarily need to occur twice") is correct and the implementation is also correct. The implementation does a simple `%q` in the end, which means that the output just restarts at the beginning. However, at the beginning there is the pair `1` and `1`, which in general is wrong due to your argument. Somehow, I have more trust in your argument than in the implementation...

Comment: Ahh, Yes, you are right! There should have a shift in index.